# What happened to the candidate stats link?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, election

During the nomination phase of the current (Aug, 2014) election there was a very helpful and informative link to candidate stats (Figure 1).  In fact the link still exists as "[More information about the candidates](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#gis.stackexchange)" on the [2014 Moderator Election page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1), although it is defunct now.  Was this intended only for the nomination phase, or is this a site error?  Either way, it would be beneficial to have these candidate stats available to the voters.

**Figure 1**

[image]

Comment: Are you after the Nomination meta questions/answers Helpful Flags stats? They are still there under the 'nomination' tab http://gis.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=nomination for all six candidates.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1 is the original link that is now working.

Comment: @Mapperz I updated the post with the correct information and dead link.

Comment: I think this is a bug so have added a tag to that effect - thanks for taking the time to write this up

Comment: Yep, [definitely looks like this is a bug of some sort](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2BaR2.png). I'll have this looked into.

Comment: Seems to be back now; all credit to Tim Post

Comment: @MarcGravell, perhaps you could post the comment as an answer?